# Is there a way to compare the variable for each thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a horse list who is going to have a race. So I created a thread for each horse to simulate the race. Each horse has this properties name and age. The track will run inside the run method. During track I like to monitor and compare each horse's/threads distance travelled.

Comment: ok I change the perso to horse. I will update the post and add the codd

Comment: @ShyamBhimani I already update the post and put my code. Id like to compare the distance travelled in each thread/horse.

Comment: I been racking my brain on how to compare the distancetravelled variable for each thread/horse. Id like to change the random speed of the trailing horse. But I can't seem to find a way how to do it. Can you help me with this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to compare the variable for each thread java

Yea.

- Declare the variable as an instance variable of the `Horse` class; e.g. add an instance variable to hold the distance traveled.  (It *has to be* an instance variable.  You can't access local variables inside some method from another thread.)
- Add a public getter method for the variable to the `Horse` class
- In the place where you want to do the comparisons:

  - iterate the `Horse` objects
  - call the getter method
  - compare the values returned.

However, there is a big gotcha.  The threads that run each `Horse` are going to be different to the thread that is looking at / comparing the positions.  Therefore all accesses to / updates to the "distance traveled" variables MUST be synchronized, or there is a risk that on thread won't see updates made by the other one.

Comment: Can you give me sample code on hor to implement is? TIA

Comment: Sorry, No.  You will learn a lot more if you work this out for yourself.